# Windows Server 2008 Application Pool set to .Net 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008

I am trying to deploy an MVC application to a server with the correct versions of .NET installed, the application pool has been set to .NET 4 but the error says .NET 2

Have a look at the screen shots below, maybe you can point me in the right direction

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server probably does not have the 4.5 framework installed. Both 4.0 and 4.5 MVC applications will run under the 4.0 app bool but if your application is complied against 4.5 you will need that installed on the target server.

Comment: .NET 4.5 is installed on the server, my issue is with that the app runs under .NET 2 and not under .NET 4 as in the App Pool settings